# PHP parsing won't find "span" tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to find the span tags on a website similar to this: http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/leagueschedule.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=14225. The tags I need are these:

[image]

However, when I use code such as the following:

```
    $my_url = 'http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/leagueschedule.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=14225';
    $html = file_get_contents($my_url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    //Put your XPath Query here
    $my_xpath_query = "//span";
    $result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

    // Create an array to hold the content of the nodes
    $statsListings = array();

    //here we loop through our results (a DOMDocument Object)
    foreach ($result_rows as $result_object) {
        $statsListings[] = $result_object->nodeValue;
    }


    echo json_encode($statsListings);
```

The only output I get is `[]`.

If I replace `$statsListings[] = $result_object->nodeValue;` with `$statsListings[] = $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;`, I still get the same `[]` as output. When there are clearly `span` tags with values, why am I getting nothing?

Comment: View the page source (not the inspector console). It looks like the document is served as a large JSON source, and assembled into HTML by JavaScript, so you will not be able to use DOMDocument to parse the HTML.  The data you want are likely somewhere in that JSON though.

Comment: There is no `span` in your html!

Comment: Does this site have a proper API to read the data directly rather than scrape it?

Comment: In the original source, these nodes may be found as `<a href="boxscore.html?gameid=2657681">Final</a>` followed by several table `<td>` elements like `<td>Thu, Apr 16</td><td> 7:05 PM</td><td> <b>2 - 3</b>`. Are those what you ultimately want?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, no I'm looking at the scoreboards up top. I can scrape the <td> tags. It's that screenshot I put in my question that I want. For some reason when I scrape like I would for the <td> tags, nothing is there.

Comment: @undone, what do you mean? How is it not in the html? I took a screen shot of it in chrome's developer tools.

Comment: What you're looking is generated by javascript or something similar(like Ajax) , if you search for `<span`   in the source code which you receive from server, there is no span tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath is not guilty at all.
Span tags are added dinamically. Just have a look at the source code of the page, not the DOM-Structure, which may be already modified by javascript, but use "view-source:" and you will see exactly the same html, as it is parsed by XPath.

It would be a good idea to have a look at the table with class **tablelines**? probably, you have there everything you may need.
You should skip "maincolor" and "tableheader", and start processing with "light" class.

```
<table width="98%" class="tablelines" cellpadding="2" border="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr class="maincolor">
    <td colspan="8" align="right">All Times Local</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableheader">
    <td width="4%">
        <b>GN</b>
    </td>
    <td nowrap width="21%">
        <b>AWAY</b>
    </td>
    <td nowrap width="21%">
        <b>HOME</b>
    </td>
    <td width="14%"><b>DATE</b></td>
    <td width="11%"><b>TIME</b></td>
    <td width="8%"><b>SCORE</b></td>
    <td nowrap align="right" width="*"><b>BOXSCORE</b></td>
    <td nowrap align="center" width="4%"><b>GS</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="light">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="teamplayerstats.html?teamid=3138&seasonid=14225">Sioux City</a>
        <b>1</b></td>
    <td><a href="teamplayerstats.html?teamid=3139&seasonid=14225">Sioux Falls</a>
        <b>5</b></td>
    <td>Tue, Apr 14</td>
    <td> 7:05 PM</td>
    <td> <b>1 - 5</b> </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a href="http://www.pointstreak.com/flashapp/index_hockey_new.html?gameid=2657671" target="_blank"><img src="/images/gamelive_icon.gif" title="Click here for Game Live!" alt="Click here for Game Live" border="0"></a>
        <a href="boxscore.html?gameid=2657671">Final</a></td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="gamesheet_full.html?gameid=2657671" target="_blank"><img src="/images/playersection/prostats/gslink.gif" border="0"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

For example, try this:

```
$my_url = 'http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/leagueschedule.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=14225';
$html = file_get_contents($my_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//Put your XPath Query here
$my_xpath_query = "//tr[@class='light']/td";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);
echo $result_rows->length;
// Create an array to hold the content of the nodes
$statsListings = array();

//here we loop through our results (a DOMDocument Object)
foreach ($result_rows as $result_object) {
    $statsListings[] = $result_object->nodeValue;
}

echo json_encode($statsListings);
```

Probably I have found what you need, and even in nice JSON form:
http://www.pointstreak.com/ajax/trending_ajax.html?action=divisionscoreboard&divisionid=12299&seasonid=14225

```
{"trending_list":null,"lacrosse_list":null,"hockey_list":null,"soccer_list":null,"baseball_list":null,"softball_list":null,"basketball_list":null,"news_list":null,"news_hockey_list":null,"news_baseball_list":null,"news_baseball_list2":null,"news_softball_list":null,"news_basketball_list":null,"games_list":[{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Sioux Falls","homescore":"4","awayteam":"Muskegon","awayscore":"2","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:05 pm","gamedate":"15\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2672134"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Muskegon","homescore":"1","awayteam":"Sioux Falls","awayscore":"6","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:15 pm","gamedate":"10\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2672133"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Muskegon","homescore":"2","awayteam":"Sioux Falls","awayscore":"3","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"1st","schedtime":"7:15 pm","gamedate":"09\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2672132"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Dubuque","homescore":"3","awayteam":"Muskegon","awayscore":"4","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:05 pm","gamedate":"05\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662061"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Muskegon","homescore":"0","awayteam":"Dubuque","awayscore":"6","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:15 pm","gamedate":"02\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662060"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Sioux Falls","homescore":"7","awayteam":"Tri-City","awayscore":"3","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:05 pm","gamedate":"02\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662055"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Muskegon","homescore":"3","awayteam":"Dubuque","awayscore":"1","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:15 pm","gamedate":"01\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662059"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Sioux Falls","homescore":"4","awayteam":"Tri-City","awayscore":"3","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:04 pm","gamedate":"01\/05","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662054"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Tri-City","homescore":"2","awayteam":"Sioux Falls","awayscore":"3","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:05 pm","gamedate":"29\/04","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2664638"},{"status":"FINAL","hometeam":"Dubuque","homescore":"7","awayteam":"Muskegon","awayscore":"3","timeremaining":"0:00","currentperiod":"3rd","schedtime":"7:05 pm","gamedate":"25\/04","link":"..\/prostats\/boxscore.html?gameid=2662058"}],"division_list":null,"site_network_title":null,"leagueshortname":"USHL","includesportlink":null,"showleaguename":0}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to scrape is the scoreboards up top. I can scrape the table with the <td> tags and such alright. For some reason the same method won't find the scoreboard's <span> tags.

Comment: I just explained why it doesn't find span tags. Because they are not here when you load the page. Just try to open this page  with disabled Javascript, you will understand what I mean.

Comment: @Jameson He explained why it's not finding the span tags - _because at the time you're scraping for them in PHP, they don't exist._ His answer is correct and his advice for fixing it is sound.

Comment: So is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: look at the post now, I have found some interesting JSON, probably it is being used for the table on the top

Comment: Ahh OK, I see it. Where exactly did you find that? I remember seeing something similar in Chrome's Developer Tools, possibly in the network section months ago.

Comment: Exactly. Chrome DevTools. "Network" tab. It lets you to find a lot of about AJAX requests.